# new templated sheet to different workbook

Tags: vba, excel, templates

In the code below, a button on a user form is creating a new sheet based off a template, and renaming it. Is there anyway to do this but have the new sheet created on a different workbook, and still have it accessed with the hyperlink? Anything helps. Thanks.

```
Dim i as byte, sh as worksheet
for i=1 to 1
Sheets("TEMPLATE").Copy after:=sheets("TEMPLATE")
set sh = activeSheet
' Do whatever you have to do with the new sheet
sh.Name = AddEmployeeUF.txtFirstname.Text + AddEmployeeUF.txtMiddleinitial.Text + AddEmployeeUF.txtLastname.Text + "Template"
ws.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ws.Range("F" & LastRow), Address:="", SubAddress:=sh.Name & "!A1", TextToDisplay:="View"
Next I
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be everything you need. Also, I got rid of that useless loop.

```
   Dim newWB As Workbook
   Dim thisWB As Workbook
   Set thisWB = ThisWorkbook
   Set newWB = GetOrCreateWB("WBName", "C:\Users\...") '<--| Opening WB you want
   thisWB.Sheets("Template").Copy after:=newWB.Sheets(1)
   With ActiveSheet '<--| the just pasted worksheet becomes the active one
   .Name = AddEmployeeUF.txtFirstname.Text + AddEmployeeUF.txtMiddleinitial.Text + AddEmployeeUF.txtLastname.Text + "Template" '<--| Name it
   ws.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ws.Range("F" & LastRow), Address:=newWB.Path & "\" & newWB.Name, SubAddress:="'" & .Name & "'!A1", TextToDisplay:="View" '<--| hyperlink to new sheet
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim i as byte, sh as worksheet
Dim newWB as Workbook
Dim thisWB as Workbook
Set thisWB = ThisWorkbook
set newWB = Application.Workbooks.Add
for i=1 to 1
    thisWB.Sheets("TEMPLATE").Copy after:=newWB.Sheets("Sheet1")
    set sh = newWB.Sheets("TEMPLATE")
    ' Do whatever you have to do with the new sheet
    sh.Name = AddEmployeeUF.txtFirstname.Text + _
              AddEmployeeUF.txtMiddleinitial.Text + _
              AddEmployeeUF.txtLastname.Text + "Template"
    ws.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ws.Range("F" & LastRow), Address:="", _
                                       SubAddress:=sh.Name & "!A1", _
                                       TextToDisplay:="View"
Next I
```

Comment: Copy method of Worksheet class failed Error

Comment: That's what I get for typing off the top of my head. See the corrected `Copy` line.

Comment: Anyway to get it so it doesn't create the new sheet in the current workbook and just the new one? Also it creates a new workbook every time, anyway to get them saved to a specific workbook when new sheets are created?